# play back sound on android sdk

Tags: android, microphone

This code below record and save as audio file 'sample.wav'

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();

recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/sample.wav");

recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

try {
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to play back (talkback) the recording without saving the audio file

Answer (score 0):

you can youse AudioRecord to record audio and AudioTrack to play.

you can see this link for example http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/06/audiorecord-and-audiotrack.html